# Problem creating new resolution in Lubuntu 16.04

Tags: lubuntu, display-resolution, xrandr

I'm trying to create a new resolution of the video, in Lubuntu 16.04.

I tried:

Generate the "Modeline"

```
cvt 1024 768 60
output: Modeline "1024x768_60.00"   63.50  1024 1072 1176 1328  768 771 775 798 -hsync +vsync
```

Create new mode

```
xrandr --newmode "1024x768_60.00"   63.50  1024 1072 1176 1328  768 771 775 798 -hsync +vsync
output: xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
```

Video name is `default`

then

```
 sudo xrandr --addmode default 1024x768_60.00
```

The new resolution appears in the list, however it does not work, when I click on apply nothing happens.

I noticed that the maximum and minimum limits are equal by running the xrandr command.

```
Screen 0: minimum 640 x 480, current 640 x 480, maximum 640 x 480
default connected 640x480+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   640x480       73.00* 
   1024x768_60.00  59.92
```

I think this is the problem ...

How could I change the maximum resolution value ??

Output info of hardware

```
lshw -C video
output:  *-display UNCLAIMED     
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 661/741/760 PCI/AGP or 662/761Gx PCIE VGA Display Adapter
       vendor: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 66MHz
       capabilities: pm agp agp-3.0 vga_controller cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:e0000000-e7ffffff memory:ed000000-ed01ffff ioport:a000(size=128)
```

Display:

[LG Flatron L1553S-SF](http://www.lg.com/us/support-product/lg-L1553S-SF)

Comment: you might want to add some information about the hardware used (graphics card/s, display/s)

Comment: Have you tried invoking your new mode by issuing a command like `xrandr --output VGA1 --mode 1024x768_60.00` where VGA1 is the video output you want to see it on?

Comment: Thanks @Phillip-ZyanKLee-Stockmann, I have edited the question by adding additional information.

Comment: Thanks @OrganicMarble. I tried, but it did not work. The strange thing is that I have other machines with the same configuration (hardware) and there appears the resolution 1024 x 768, this machine tried to reinstall the Lubuntu but the problem persists.